# FFMPEG RTSP streaming

Tags: ffmpeg, udp, streaming, rtsp

I need help with ffmpeg streaming. I have a Grandstream GSC3510 Speaker that it also works like a telephone. I need to configure a rtsp server for streaming 1 file or mutiple files (if possible) of music. I tried straming with UDP that worked but only RSTP format can be streamed and if a call comes in, interupted while call is in place and then continued when the call is over.
my code for udp worked fine:

`ffmpeg -stream_loop -1 -re -i C:\relax.mp3 -vol 30 -filter_complex aresample=16000,asetnsamples=n=160 -acodec g722 -ac 1 -vn -f rtp udp://239.255.255.241:5555`

but I cant get RTSP to work Im kind of a new at this so I would really appreciate some help.

Comment: add the ffmpeg cmd that you have tried and is not working..

Answer (score 0):

Please try the [live555 RTSP](http://www.live555.com/mediaServer/) streaming server to stream the data to grand stream speaker.

Comment: can you maybe help me with some code? I really cant get it to work...

Comment: Reference sample code , example are all present in the link above.. adding again for reference http://www.live555.com/liveMedia/